# Using Jmeter for load testing of a standalone java application

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I have to do load test for a stand alone java application. I have just one class file can i do the testing with Jmeter ? If yes then can some body throw some light over it or share any tutorial?

Actually when i went through net, i got to know that Jmeter is meant for testing web application only but i got few blogs regarding testing of stand alone application as well but they were not very much helpful.

Please help.

Comment: How are the users going to access this application? What kind of load do you want to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load test an application you need to apply load to it. Jmeter is used to apply load to web sites by simulating users of that web site. It won't help you very much unless you are writing a web site.

For your stand alone application you will need to work out a way to simulate lots of users (usually that will involve finding or writing another program to do so) and then do that.

For example to load test a restful web service to store documents I wrote a program that looped through every file in a folder uploading them all, then downloaded the uploaded files and compared the two. We then ran that up on multiple computers simultaneously looping thousands of times through the folder. That simulated heavy load from multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

> Apache JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and
>   dynamic resources (Files, Web dynamic languages - PHP, Java, ASP.NET,
>   etc. -, Java Objects, Data Bases and Queries, FTP Servers and more).
>   It can be used to simulate a heavy load on a server, group of servers,
>   network or object to test its strength or to analyze overall
>   performance under different load types. You can use it to make a
>   graphical analysis of performance or to test your server/script/object
>   behavior under heavy concurrent load.

via http://jmeter.apache.org/

so maybe it does not suite...